# Android DatePicker style messed up

Tags: android, datepicker, styles

i'm developping an android app and at some point i needed to use a DatePicker. I'm using the bit of code from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#DatePicker). But the DatePickerFragment that pops up has his style all messed up like this :

[image: Screenshot]

This is the layout of the activity :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="narthe.compteur_km.ExportActivity"
android:background="#ff1a2530"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView android:id="@+id/showMyDate"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/myDatePickerButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/pick_date"
    android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog" />

<Button
    style="@style/customEditButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/exporter"
    android:id="@+id/exportButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

So what am i doing wrong ? Is there some style of mine overriding the native style ? (Tried to remove the "style="@style/customEditButton" line in second button but same result)

Comment: You're not showing the layout containing the datepicker.

Comment: make sure that your activity that displays the time picker extends FragmentActivity instead of the standard Activity class.

Comment: @KristyWelsh : Well i don't have any layout for the date picker, i'm just building a fragment with the code on the page i linked.

Answer (score 0):

i realised i had defined a global background color for the whole app in styles.xml as follow :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#ff1a2530</item>
</style>
```

So i removed it and i got the right style for the date picker.